# PHP preg_match specify number and get the section id by the area of the specific number

Tags: php

I want to get the section id from this text, according to the entrance number
period.

```
<li id="section-1" role="example" label="1 - 6">
<li id="section-2" role="example" label="6 - 12">
<li id="section-3" role="example" label="12 - 18">
<li id="section-4" role="example" label="18 - 24">
```

for example when i enter **8** period will be **6 - 12** and i will get "**section-2**" , **21** will get "**section-4**" etc...

Comment: Good grief.  There has to be a better way? First of all, how do you expect this to happen in PHP? Is this HTML in a string somewhere and we're going to search / parse it?  Second, is the HTML the **whole page**, or just the relevant bits of li, like you have here?  Third, what PHP have you tried?  (I would be impressed if there is ANY regular expression that can do this, but hey - regular expressions are awesome!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you know what you're doing I'd go for a function like this:

```
function find_section($html, $value)
{
    static $pattern = '/<li id="section\\-(\\d+)" role="example" label="(\\d+) \- (\\d+)"(>)/';
    $offset = 0;

    while (preg_match($pattern, $html, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, $offset))
    {
        $section_id = (int) $matches[1][0];
        $range_min = (int) $matches[2][0];
        $range_max = (int) $matches[3][0];
        $offset = $matches[4][1] + 1;

        if ($value >= $range_min && $value < $range_max)
        { return 'section-' . $section_id; }
    }

    return null;
}
```

I personally do not know of a possibility with one single `preg_match` call. I'd say that's not possible. The above function will scan the given HTML string for your `li`-elements' pattern, extract their range and compare the given value against it.

Depending on what you actually want to achieve, e.g. if you're searching for sections for multiple values, you may want to scan all `li`-elements in a first go and store them as easier accessible data (arrays or stdclass objects for example), so you won't have to re-match the whole HTML code each time you search for a value's section.

A simple small testing code for the above function (just to show how it works) would be:

```
$html = '
    <li id="section-1" role="example" label="1 - 6">
    <li id="section-2" role="example" label="6 - 12">
    <li id="section-3" role="example" label="12 - 18">
    <li id="section-4" role="example" label="18 - 24">
';

echo find_section($html, 8) . "\n";
echo find_section($html, 21) . "\n";
echo find_section($html, 50) . "\n";
```

Output:

```
section-2
section-4
```

(Tested with PHP 5.5.15)

Comment: Thank you very much ,i will try it .

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like this:

```
<?php

$text = '<li id="section-1" role="example" label="1 - 6">
<li id="section-2" role="example" label="6 - 12">
<li id="section-3" role="example" label="12 - 18">
<li id="section-4" role="example" label="18 - 24">';

$pattern = '<li id="section-([0-9]+)" role="example" label="([0-9]+) - ([0-9]+)">';

function find_section($value) {
    global $text, $pattern;

    preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $results);

    $index = 0;
    foreach($results[3] as $max) {
        if ($value < $max) {
            break;
        }
        $index++;
    }

    return "section-{$results[1][$index]}   {$results[2][$index]} - {$results[3][$index]}\n";
}

echo find_section(6);  // section-2   6 - 12
echo find_section(21); // section-4   18 - 24
```

http://ideone.com/uCzCkm